# Comparison of strings not returning correct information

Tags: powershell, if-statement

We're working with a text file that contains many different types of reports. Some of those reports need to either have some words changed or just copy them over exactly as they are.

The file has to stay a single text file, so the idea is to move through the file, comparing the lines. If a line is found that is a "ReportType1", then we need to change some wording, so we go into an inner loop, extracting the data and changing words as we go. The loop ends when it reaches a footer in the report and should move on to the next report.

We've tried -match, -like, -contains, -eq, but it never works quite like it's supposed to. We either get data that's been changed/reformatted that shouldn't be or we're only getting the header data.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Text.RegularExpressions

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$content = @()

$inputFile   = "drive\folder\inputfile.txt"
$outputFile  = "drive\folder\outputfile.txt"

#This will retrieve the total number of lines in the file
$FileContent = Get-Content $inputFile
$FileLineCount = $FileContent | Measure-Object -Line
$TotalLines = $FileContent.Count

$TotalLines++ #Need to increase by one; the last line is blank

$startLine   = 0
$lineCounter = 0

#Start reading the file; this is the Header section
#Number of lines may vary, but data is copied over word
#for word
foreach($line in Get-Content $inputfile)
{
    $startLine++
    If($line -match "FOOTER")
    {
        [void]$content.Add( $line )
        break
    }
    else
    {
        [void]$content.Add( $line )
    }
}
## ^^This section works perfectly

#Start reading the body of the file
Do {
    #Start reading from the current position
    #This should change with each report read
    $line = Get-Content $inputFile | select -Skip $startLine

    If($line -match "ReportType1") #If it's a ReportType1, some wording needs to be changed
    {
        #Start reading the file from the current position
        #Should loop through this record only
        foreach($line in Get-Content $inputFile | select -skip $startline) 
        {
            If($line -match "FOOTER") #End of the current record
            {
                [void]$content.Add( $line )
                break #break out of the loop and continue reading the file from the new current position
            }
            elseif ($line -match "OldWord") #Have to replace a word on some lines
            {
                $line = $line.Replace("OldWord","NewWord")
                [void]$content.Add( $line ) 
            }
            else
            { 
                [void]$content.Add( $line ) 
            }
            $startline++                
        }
    }
    else
    {
         If($line -match "ReportType2") #ReportType2 can just be copied over line for line
         {
             #Start reading the file from the current position
             #Should loop through this record only
             foreach($line in Get-Content $inputFile | select -skip $startline) 
             {
                If($line -match "FOOTER") #End of the current record
                {
                    [void]$content.Add( $line )
                    break #break out of the loop and continue reading the file from the new current position
                }
                else
                { 
                    [void]$content.Add( $line ) 
                }
                $startline++                
        }
    }
    $startline++
} until ($startline -eq $TotalLines)

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines( $outputFile, $content ) | Out-Null
```

It sort of works, but we're getting some unexpected behavior. The reports look fine and all, but it's changing words in "ReportType2", even though the code isn't set up to do that. It's like it's only going through the first IF statement. But how can it be if the lines don't match up?

We know the $startline variable is increasing through the iterations, so it's not like it's stuck on one line. However, doing 'Write-Host' shows $line is always "ReportType1", which can't be true because the lines are showing up in the reports like they're supposed to be.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
<header data>
.
43 lines (although this can vary)
.
<footer>
<ReportType1> 
. 
x number of lines (varies)
. 
<footer> 
<ReportType2> 
. 
x number of lines (varies)
. 
<footer>
```

And so on and so forth, until the end of the file. The different types of reports are all mixed together.

All we can figure is we're missing something, probably pretty obvious, that will get this to output the data correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One thing that would cause unexpected issues is using `$line` as your `foreach` iterator and then using it for variable assignment within those same loops. I think all places that have `$line = ` should be changed to `$SomethingElse =`. Or just use `[void]$content.Add(($line.Replace("OldWord","NewWord")))` with no additional variable assignment. At least for experimental purposes, let's only use `$line` in one loop. Give the other loops another iterator $variable and give all variable assignments something else unique as well. If there are still problems, then we can look at flow control.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Okay, tried changing all of the instances of `$line` to be more specific to their respective loops. Still having the same issue where ReportType2 is getting data changed. I did add a `Write-Host` line after each `If("ReportType)` comparison and ReportType1 is the only one that ever comes up. So it's like that first IF statement is always evaluating to 'true' and the second is always 'false'.

Comment: If we have a file that contains many lines of text with the first line containing ReportType1 and a 50th line containing ReportType2, `(Get-Content File) -match "ReportType1"` will always be true and so would `(Get-Content File) -match "ReportType2"`. Are you verifying that you don't have both in the section of text you are comparing?

Comment: Some sample data:
43 lines of header information
<foooter>
<ReportType1>
.
x number of lines
.
<footer>
<ReportType2>
.
x number of lines
.
<footer>

The number of reports varies day to day. The first line of reading the body of the file is to skip X lines down, read that section, then skip to the next section. And, as I said, it appears to be sort-of working since it's pulling the ReportType2 data; however, it's never evaluating ReportType1 as false. The lines we're comparing are specific to the reports. So the line "ReportType1" doesn't ever appear in "ReportType2" data.

Comment: @Hinton, please add the sample data directly to your question, don't post it (or any clarifications) in comments. Also, please consider providing an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or as close as you can get to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you want. Just replace the values for `$oldword` and `$newword` with your word replacements (these are case-insensitive for now) and the value of `$report` with the report header you want to update.

```
$oldword = "Liability"
$newword = "Asset"
$report = "ReportType1"
$data = Get-Content Input.txt
$reports = $data | Select-String -Pattern $Report -AllMatches
$footers = $data | Select-String -Pattern "FOOTER" -AllMatches
$startindex = 0
[collections.arraylist]$output = foreach ($line in $reports) {
    $section = ($line.linenumber-1),($footers.linenumber.where({$_ -gt $line.linenumber},'First')[0]-1)
    if ($startindex -lt $section[0]-1) {
        $data[$startindex..($section[0]-1)]
    }
    if ($startindex -eq $section[0]-1) {
        $data[$startindex]
    }
    $data[$section[0]..$section[1]] -replace $oldword,$newword
    $startindex = $section[1]+1
}
if ($startindex -eq $data.count-1) {
    [void]$output.Add($data[$startindex])
}
if ($startindex -lt $data.count-1) {
    [void]$output.Add($data[$startindex..($data.count-1)])
}
$output | Set-Content Output.txt
```

**Code Explanation:**

The intention of `$oldword` is to be used in a regex replace operation. So any special regex characters will need to be escaped. I have opted to do that for you here. If you want to update the string that is to be replaced, you only need to update the characters between the quotes. This is case-insensitive when we pass it to the `-replace` operator.

`$newword` is simply the string that will replace the output of `$oldword`. It does not require any special handling unless the string contains special PowerShell characters. The replacement text will appear as is including the case.

`$report` is the name of the header of the section where you want to replace data. This is case-insensitive when we pass it to `Select-String -Pattern`.

`$data` is just the contents of the file as an array. Each line of the file is an indexed item in the array.

The first `Select-String` does regex matching with the regex pattern being `-Pattern $Report`. The reason it uses regex is because we did not specify the `-SimpleMatch` parameter. `-AllMatches` is added to capture every instance of `$Report` within the file. The output is stored in `$Reports`. $Reports is an array of `MatchInfo` objects, which have properties that we will use like `Line` and `LineNumber`.

The second `Select-String` does regex matching with the regex pattern being `-Pattern "FOOTER"`. You could make this a variable instead if it could possibly change. The reason it uses regex is because we did not specify the `-SimpleMatch` parameter. `-AllMatches` is added to capture every instance of `FOOTER` within the file.

`$startIndex` is used to keep track of where we are in the array. It plays a role in helping us grab the different sections of the selected text.

`$output` is an arraylist that contains the lines we are reading from `$data` and the selected text that matches your report header (the `Select-String -Pattern $Report` output). It is an arraylist so that we have access to the `Add()` method for more efficiently constructing a collection. It is much more efficient than using `+=` and custom object arrays.

The heart of the code starts with a `foreach` loop that loops through each object in `$Reports`. Each current object is stored in `$line`. `$Line` will become a `MatchInfo` object as a result. `$section` is an array of line numbers (offset by -1 because indexes start at 0) that contain the next `$report` match through the next available `FOOTER` match. The `if` statements within the loop are just dealing with certain conditions like if the `$report` matches the first or second line of the file or the first or second line of the next section. The `foreach` loop will ultimately output all text leading up to the first `$report` match, the text within each `$report` match including the `FOOTER` match, and the text between all matches.

The `if` statements after the `foreach` loop add the rest of the file beyond the last match to `$output`.

**Issues With Initial Attempt:**

In your attempt, the thing creating a problem for you is the order of the reports in the file. If ReportType1 shows up after ReportType2 in the file, then the first `If` statement will always be true. You are not examining a block of lines. Instead, you are examine all remaining lines starting from a certain line. I'll try to illustrate what I'm saying with an example:

Below is a sample file with line numbers

```
1. <footer>
2. <ReportType2>
3. data
4. data
5. <footer>
6. <ReportType1>
7. data
8. <footer>
```

Your startline will be 1 after reaching the first footer. You then read all lines skipping 1, which includes line 2 and line 6. `($line | select-object -skip 1) -match "ReportType1"` will find a match and return `$true` in an `if` statement. On the next for loop, you will iterate until startline becomes 5. Then `($line | select-object -skip 5) -match "ReportType1"` will also find a match. The only way your logic will work is if the ReportType1 section comes before ReportType2 in the file.

Comment: This is good; very good. And it's almost what we're looking for. However, if the line/section is "ReportType1", we have to do a great deal of formatting on the text (also depends on what kind of report). Looking at the code, I can see where's it iterating through the lines of the section, but anything we do to try and test for certain words or phrases to reformat within that loop, other than `$oldword, $newword`, it breaks and we don't get the output. I'm not asking you to write the code for me, but would you please explain a little what the code is doing so we can modify it for our purposes?

Comment: @Hinton, can you explain more specifically about your expectations? I'll add some further explanation. This can be made more dynamic by turning it into a function as well.

Comment: And I was thinking a function (or several functions) might be the way to go for this, but couldn't seem to get it to work. So, under ReportType1, we would have several different types of sub-reports. Based on what kind of sub-report, we need to change and/or reformat certain lines. So, we find ReportType1, find the sub-report type and then proceed to loop through that section/report to change lines/words. Make sense?

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. After looking it over and testing it several different ways, we just can't get it to break things out like we need. As I said, it's very good and very close, but the sub-reports are what's breaking it. If it was just the two reports and changing a few things, this would be perfect. Again, many thanks for the input and explanation.